# Error using ==> fprintf Function is not defined for 'sym' inputs

Tags: matlab, printf

This is my MATLAB code. The function trapezoidal() is defined separately and it works fine.

```
syms x;

f = 10 + 2 * x - 6 * (x^2) + 5 * (x^4);

a = 0;
b = 2;

ans_3points = trapezoidal(f, a, b, 3);
ans_5points = trapezoidal(f, a, b, 5);
ans_7points = trapezoidal(f, a, b, 7);

fprintf('Integral estimate for three equally spaced points is %f.\n', ans_3points);
fprintf('Integral estimate for five equally spaced points is %f.\n', ans_5points);
fprintf('Integral estimate for seven equally spaced points is %f.\n', ans_7points);

actual_ans = int(f, 0, 2);

error_3points = 100 * (actual_ans - ans_3points) / actual_ans;
error_5points = 100 * (actual_ans - ans_5points) / actual_ans;
error_7points = 100 * (actual_ans - ans_7points) / actual_ans;

fprintf('Percentage relative error for three equally spaced points is %f.\n', error_3points);
fprintf('Percentage relative error for five equally spaced points is %f.\n', error_5points);
fprintf('Percentage relative error for seven equally spaced points is %f.\n', error_7points);
```

But this gives the following error at the line that prints error_3points: 
??? Error using ==> fprintf
Function is not defined for 'sym' inputs.

I haven't put any 'sym' inputs in fprintf() have I?
ans_3points, ans_5points, ans_7points are printed without any problem.
The errors are calculated but when I checked they were displayed as fractions.
What exactly is the problem in this code? I really can't figure it out.
Thank you.

Function `trapezoidal`:

```
function l = trapezoidal(f, a, b, n)

N = n - 1;  % N - the number of segmets

syms x;

series_sum = 0;

for i = (0 : (N - 1))
    series_sum = series_sum + subs(f, x, xterm(i, a, b, n)) + subs(f, x, xterm((i + 1), a, b, n));
end

l = series_sum * (b - a) / (2 * N);
```

Comment: What data type does `trapezoidal` return?

Comment: The function trapezoidal returns a float.

Comment: Can you post that function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in using the function `int`

```
actual_ans = int(f, 0, 2);
```

`actual_ans' is still a symbolic variable, even if it is a constant. You can translate it into a numeric variable with

```
actual_ans = double(actual_ans);
```

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you very much. Changing the type using the above method gave an error but     actual_ans = cast(actual_ans, 'double'); worked.

Comment: Strange...it worked for me, probably depends on the Matlab version