# MATLAB: Error using fprintf Function is not defined for 'sym' inputs

Tags: matlab, printf

```
syms x;
y(x)=(-1/10)*(sin(x)+3*cos(x));

for i=2:1:N+1
    t=a+(i-1)*h;
    z=y(t);
    fprintf('\n\tx\t\ty\n')
    fprintf('%f %f\n',t,z) 
end
```

I declared x as a syms so I can use it to represent a function. My problem now is when I want to print the y values using the t values from the loop, I get an error saying that fprintf is not defined on sym inputs.

Comment: @TroyHaskin I believe the solution for that question isn't a complete answer for this one. The numeric part is solved by it, but displaying the symbolic equation with `fprintf` is not.

Comment: @Doresoom True, but poster says "y values".  I did consider posting the `char()` option as well, but you beat me to it.

Comment: @TroyHaskin Good point! I missed that, since I just copied and ran the code. The first error thrown is on printing the equations. The second error is thrown when attempting to print the `z/y` variable. I started with troubleshooting the first error I ran into, and didn't realize that `z` was still symbolic until I had fixed the first error.

Answer (score 3):

Specify your symbolic inputs to `fprintf` with `%s` placeholders and use `char` to convert them to characters.

For example:

```
fprintf('\n\t%s\t\t%s\n',char(x),char(y))
```

As alexmogavero points out in the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25784682/201800), you'll also need to convert your second fprintf symbolic input of `z` to a numeric value:

```
fprintf('%f %f\n',t,double(z))
```